# Finding a closed form for recurrence relations $a_n=na_{n-1}+1$ and $a_n=na_{n-1}+n$

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursion

Consider the sequence defined by
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0=1\\
a_n=n\cdot a_{n-1}+1 & \text{if }n\ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
Find a closed form for $a_n$.

Second case is as follows:
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0=1\\
a_n=n\cdot a_{n-1}+n & \text{if }n\ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
Find a closed form for $a_n$.

Comment: Try $b_n:=a_n/n!$.

Comment: Can you please help me to understand how I can derive that

Comment: Is there any common method available like the presented here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942721/finding-a-closed-form-for-a-recurrence-relation-a-n-3a-n-14a-n-2?rq=1

Comment: The solution to the first one is $a(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k!=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k}$. However, I'm not sure how to derive it.

Comment: @C.Melton $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkk!\ne n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1k$$ Was $\frac1k$ a typo for $\frac1{k!}$?

Answer (score 7):

Try [exponential generating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_(EGF)) functions (and another [link here](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=353&lmm=1)). For example, let's look at the first recurrence
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}\color{red}{a_n}\frac{x^n}{n!}=
1+\sum\limits_{n=1}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\\
1+\sum\limits_{n=1}(n\cdot a_{n-1} + 1)\frac{x^n}{n!}=
1+\sum\limits_{n=1}a_{n-1} \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!} + \sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\\
x\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}a_{n-1} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right) + \sum\limits_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\\
x\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}a_{n} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}\right) + \sum\limits_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\\
x\cdot f(x) + e^x$$
or (applying series multiplication, below the 2nd defition [here](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=354&lmm=0))
$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1-x}=\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}x^n\right)=\\
\sum\limits_{n=0}\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!}\cdot 1\right)x^n=
\sum\limits_{n=0}\color{red}{\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{n!}{i!}\right)}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
and finally
$$a_n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{n!}{i!}=
n!\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$a_n=na_{n-1}+1$$
$$\Rightarrow a_n=n(n-1)a_{n-2}+1+n$$
$$\Rightarrow a_n=n(n-1)(n-2)a_{n-3}+1+n+n(n-2)$$

Continuing so on we get,
$$a_n=a_0n!+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {n!}{k!}=n!\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k!}\right)=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$$

Similarly you can solve for the second case to get,
$$a_n=n!\left(1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!}\right)$$